# Will arithmetic on two sequences ever equal some value

Tags: sequences-and-series

I wrote a question a few days ago, but it seems to have disappeared. My question is this:

If I have 2 sequences:

```
Sequence1 = {1002, 996, 990... 1 }  : essentially S1n-6

Sequence 2 = {2, 10, 18 .... x} : essentially S2n + 8
```

And if I want to see if nth term in sequence 1 divided by the nth term in sequence 2 = 27. So something like this:

S1n/S2n = 27

Example:

```
1002/2 != 27
996/10 != 27
990/18 != 27
.
.
and so on.
```

Sequence 1's first term will always be larger than sequence 2's first term .

Sequence 1's last term will always be > 0 and Sequence 2's first term will always be >0

As well Sequence 1 and Sequence 2 will always have the same number of terms

Thus if I know the first number in sequence 1 the first number is 1001 and will subtract by 6, and I know the first number is sequence 2 is 2 and will add by 8, is there a quick way to see if in any term the division will equal to 27. I am just interested in knowing if the division of any terms are equal to 27 (true or false), I am not interested in knowing what terms they are or what their values are, knowing that would just be an added bonus, but it is not what I am after.

Of course, I could go through each term in the element and manually calculate it, but this will be time-consuming so I am just wondering if there is a quicker way with the information I know in the beginning to calculate this?

The numbers I use here are just examples, I am looking for a more general method where it can be applied to any numbers.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please use MathJax when writing questions.

Comment: Um.... what exactly is your question?  The $n$ term (after the first term) is $1002 - 6n$ and the $n$ term (after the first term) is $2+8n$ so just solve for $\frac {1002-6n}{2+8n} = 27$.  If that has an integer solution that's it.

Comment: Are you asking if some *corresponding* terms have the ratio $27$ (i.e. $S_{1n}=27S_{2n}$ or if *any* terms have that ratio (i.e. $S_{1n}=27S_{2m}$ ?

Comment: MathJax reference: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you'll find an explicit form for each sequence $S_1,S_2$ in terms of $n$, rather than a recursive definition. Then you can perhaps do some algebra to see how it'd go.

For instance, if we let the first term of each sequence be the $n=1$ term, then

$$S_{1,n} = 1001 - 5(n-1) \;\;\;\;\; S_{2,n} = 2 + 8(n-1)$$

Then of course, equivalently,

$$S_{1,n} = 1006 - 5n \;\;\;\;\; S_{2,n} = -6 + 8n$$

We want to see if there exists a positive integer $n$ such that

$$\frac{S_{1,n}}{S_{2,n}} = \frac{1006 - 5n}{-6 + 8n} \overset ? = 27$$

Try to solve for $n$. Then we get that

$$1006 - 5n = 27(-6+8n) = 216n-162$$

which, grouping like terms and solving for $n$, implies

$$221n = 1168 \implies n = \frac{1168}{221} \approx 5.285$$

This, however, is not an integer, which means there exists no part of either sequence (even if extended infinitely) such that their ratio is $27$.

Comment: Thanks, this is basically what I was looking for!